# Images not recognized inside of a popup window (Sikuli)

Tags: java, image, similarity, sikuli

I've wrote a java program using Sikuli which navigates through numerous pages of a flash application. Everything seems to work up until I get to a popup window, and then it's unable to recognize images in the window.

I've tried recapturing the images, and the Sikuli IDE recognizes them when I do an image compare on the current screen. Which leads me to believe that it's not related to similarity being too high.

Any possible ideas or solutions would be helpful.

Thanks,

Additional information:

```
if (screen.exists(continue_overview_img.similar(similarity),timeout) != null) {
screen.wait(2.0);
screen.click(continue_overview_img);
}
```

[error] Region.exists: seems that imagefile could not be found on disk

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you are not able to match images within the popup? If so, have you tried leveraging similarity threshold? Check [this doc](http://doc.sikuli.org/match.html).

After seeing the error message the problem seems to be the image you check cannot be found by the script you run. Make sure the path you provide for the image is on your classpath.

In order to verify that try using absolute path.

Comment: Sorry, I may not have been as clear as I could have been.

I've tried adjusting the similarity threshold with no luck. It doesn't seem to be the cause, because I'm still able to recognize the non-popup (main window) images fine. It's the popup images that I can't seem to key off of.

Comment: Does it work in IDEs step-by-step mode? Another question is do you run this script on you virtual machine or desktop? Because there are known issues with virtual monitors.

Comment: It's running on my desktop. I haven't tried it in the Sikuli IDE since I'm more familiar with Eclipse. Although I did pull up the IDE to use the "Matching Preview" feature, and it located the image fine (in the troublesome popup, that is). Just doesn't seem to find it when I'm running the program. I'll try and create a short script in the IDE to test it. I'll report back with my findings. Thanks.

Comment: I set it up in the Sikuli IDE and it worked as expected. I had it click the button that creates the popup, and it was successfully able to click a button inside the popup without any difficulty. My next step was to copy the exact code (find and click) and the exact images into my java application to see if they would work. Unfortunately I'm still receiving the same error. I edited my post to provide the code and error message. Thanks again.